# Rollup failed to resolve import "highcharts/modules/.js" when running "nuxt build"

Tags: highcharts, nuxt.js, nuxt3

#### Installed Versions:

Nuxt 3.10.3
nuxt-highcharts: 3.1.1

#### Problem

I have installed [nuxt-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-highcharts/v/1.0.8) and added the dependency in the `nuxt.config.ts` file like this:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({ modules: [ 'nuxt-highcharts' ], })
```

When I now run `nuxt build` I get the following error:

```
ERROR  Nuxt Build Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "highcharts/modules/.js" from "virtual:nuxt:/frontend/.nuxt/nuxt-highcharts.hcMods.js".
```

The weird thing is, that there isn't any `nuxt-highcharts.hcMods.js` file inside the `.nuxt` folder. How can this issue be resolved?

#### What I already tried

- Reinstalling all modules after removing node_modules folder and package.lock.json

Answer (score 2):

From what I noticed, this library is not compatible with your version of Nuxt:
[image: nuxt-highcharts-version]

FYI: nuxt-highcharts is not an official highcharts wrapper, it is made by someone in the community so I suggest you contact this person directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the officially supported `highcharts-vue` package which now fully supports Vue 3 (and thus, can work with Nuxt 3 and TypeScript).

We've just released v2.0.0 on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-vue

If you'd like to use it in your Nuxt 3 project, here are some steps:

1. Create a `highcharts.client.js` file in the `/plugins` directory for Nuxt:

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue';
import stockInit from 'highcharts/modules/stock';

export default defineNuxtPlugin({
   name: 'highcharts-vue',
   parallel: true,
   setup (nuxtApp) {
       if (typeof Highcharts === 'object') {
           stockInit(Highcharts);
       }
       nuxtApp.vueApp.use(HighchartsVue);
   }
});
```

In this file you can set up Highcharts with the modules that you'd like to use.

2. Register the plugin in your `nuxt.config.ts` file:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ... the rest of your config
    plugins: [
        // Ensure this runs on client side only
        { src: '~/plugins/highcharts.client.js', mode: 'client' }
    ]
});
```

3. Use the `highcharts` component in your `.vue` files:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const options = ref({
    title: {
        text: 'My chart'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3]
    }]
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <highcharts :options="options" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Please let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove your node_modules + package-lock.json + any others of the same and re-run the package installs(e.g. npm run build or something like that). Sometimes things get hooked up wrong.

Comment: This wasn't able to fix my issue